# Custom widget for email login in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to define a custom widget (custom Cassius styles in particular) for the Email Login form. The Email Auth plugin expose default handlers for

- registerHandler
- forgotPasswordHandler
- setPasswordHandler

(https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/yesod-auth-1.4.15/Yesod-Auth-Email.html#g:5)

But there is no one for the login handler, which default widget seems to be defined in the non-exported function `emailLoginHandler` here: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/yesod-auth-1.4.15/src/Yesod.Auth.Email.html#emailLoginHandler

I'd like to have `login.hamlet` and `login.cassius` in `templates/`. How could I do that?

Comment: I don't remember the details from that module, but from your description, it looks like an oversight in the yesod-auth package, and we should just add the function as a method in the type class.

Comment: I recently added JSON support to the Email Auth module. So you can use that as a workaround for now.

Comment: Yesod-Auth defines `loginHandler` apparently, and it says: ""Override if you need fancy widget containers, additional functionality, or an entirely custom page."", but If I make a new handler and a widget it needs a form with the email and passwords input, but not sure what to do with that input afterwards

Comment: I, personally, had little luck getting my override to `loginHandler` working, so an alternative is also to override `authLayout` in the `YesodAuth` instance, and then add your own styles to the layout file there.

Comment: @Tehnix oh! didn't thought about that, it will do the trick in the mean while, thanks!

Comment: @DanielCampoverde-alx741 I've tried overriding getting the `authLayout` but can't seem to get the types right. Would you mind posting your solution (or at least what you can of it)?

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo my solution was a hack, but now there is a way. Will post it here in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no way to achieve that at the moment, so I just wrote a bunch of hacky JS in `default-layout.julius` to modify the DOM on the fly whenever the right elements are found and adding CSS attributes as well.

But now the `yesod-auth` package exports `emailLoginHandler` ([here](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.4/yesod-auth-1.4.17/Yesod-Auth-Email.html#v:emailLoginHandler)) and `defaultEmailLoginHandler` as well so it's now easy to modify it just like the other default handlers in the module.